# Is there any way to sync data in MySQL with Firebase?

Tags: mysql, firebase, laravel-5, firebase-realtime-database

Since I couldn't find a way to delete and update objects in Firebase using Laravel5, I need a way. So can I know how to pass MySQL data to Firebase?

Comment: There is no direct import. The topic has been covered a few times. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+mysql

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the data from mysql database using loop and push it to firebase

```
Map<String,String>data=new Hashmap<String,String>();
data.put(retrieved string);
Ref.push().setValue(data);
```

Am not sure ,but give it a try.